# Drag and drop components in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop a dashboard in ReactJS and I plan to do draggable components, for example like a Spotify playlist where I drag a song to another position and the other songs auto adjust their position and don't overlap, and I wanted to know if anyone knows of a way to do this, since I searched and the only thing I found was draggable components that can overlap each other.

Edit:
Thank you for the suggestion, [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Use plugin React dnd - https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several React libraries that can help you create draggable components with auto-adjustment, such as React DnD (Drag and Drop) and React Beautiful DnD. Both of these libraries have features for creating draggable lists, like the Spotify playlist you mentioned, where items automatically adjust their position when dragged and dropped.